# How do I force two observable to execute in my desired order in angular?

Tags: angular, observable

In my angular application I used 2 observable one for edit data and the other one for select all data.

here is my pieces of codes:

Main piece that I want to observers execute in my desired order

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.mpchange._id = result.id;
    this.mpchange.measureTitle = result.title;
    this.mpchange.measureDescription = result.description;
    this.mpchange.measureSymbol = result.symbol;
    this.mpserv.editbyid(result.id, this.mpchange).subscribe( // <<-- first observer
      x => console.log(x),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Complete')
    );
    this.refresh(); // <<-- second observer
  });
```

first observer calls a method that edits my database document and second one select all data from my database.
In fact my goal is to show the user edited data but it doesn't work properly.
When it executes at most second observer executes earlier than first and sometimes first is earlier then second.

In back end console I received these lines :

```
GET /mea/getall 200 3.170 ms - 615
PUT /mea/editbyid/5ce937907d656012902702cb 200 213.014 ms - 28
```

It shows that second method executes earlier.

Even I tried to place `this.refresh()` within subscribe like this :

```
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.mpchange._id = result.id;
    this.mpchange.measureTitle = result.title;
    this.mpchange.measureDescription = result.description;
    this.mpchange.measureSymbol = result.symbol;
    this.mpserv.editbyid(result.id, this.mpchange).subscribe( // <<-- first observer
      x => {
            console.log(x);
            this.refresh(); // <<-- second observer placed here
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('Complete')
    );
  });
```

But result was the same.

`refresh()` method is here:

```
private refresh() {
  this.mpserv.getall().subscribe(
    x => {
      this.mp = [];
      x.forEach(elementj => {
        this.mp.push(elementj);
      });
      this.filltoelements(this.mp);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MeasureTypeElemetns>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
      this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
    },
    err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
  );
}
```

Here is my edit method:

```
private editone() {
  this.mpserv.editbyid(this.mpchange._id, this.mpchange).subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Complete')
  );
}
```

I even used `forkJoin` operator like this:

```
forkJoin(
  [
  this.mpserv.editbyid(this.mpchange._id, this.mpchange).subscribe(
    x => console.log(x),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('Editing Completed')
  ),

  this.mpserv.getall().subscribe(
    x => {
      this.mp = [];
      x.forEach(elementj => {
        this.mp.push(elementj);
      });
      this.filltoelements(this.mp);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<MeasureTypeElemetns>(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
      this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
    },
    err => console.error('Refresh got an error: ' + err),
    () => console.log('Refresh completed')
  )
  ]
);
```

but It doesn't work properly.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the second version is not working?

Comment: @DanielHabenicht Yeah, I'm sure. Also I used concat and forkjoin either but result was the same!

Comment: Can you add `this.mpserv.editbyid()` content code into your question ? Because it's not possible that `this.refresh()` is called first in your second example.
You NodeJS server can need restart too...

Comment: @Gilsdav Yeah, I edited my question. I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `concatall()` method. So it worked properly.

```
const streamOne = this.mpserv
  .deleteonebyid(obj.id)
  .pipe(
     finalize(() => console.log('1-deleted one document.'))
  );
const streamTwo = this.true_clearElements();
const streamThree = this.true_refresh();
const streamFour = this.pginator_change();
const source = of(streamOne, streamTwo, streamThree, streamFour);
source.pipe(concatAll()).subscribe();
```